# Query not finding the needed row with SELECT

Tags: mysql

This Query cant find B4 ...

Why ?

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable.mytable WHERE A='Ok;ä' AND NOT B='1' AND NOT C='' AND NOT C=NULL
```

Table:

```
  A |B| C
----------
Ok;ä|1|
Ok;ä|2|NULL
Ok;ä|3|
Ok;ä|4|TRUE
```

Info:

- MySQL version: 5.7.14 on Win64 with InnoDB.
- Need this query in PHP.
- Tested this query in PHP and MySQL Workbench.
- (All columns are TEXT)

Comment: `AND C IS NOT NULL` not `AND NOT C=NULL`. Also, you don't need to enclose integers in quotes, although unless disabled, an implicit conversion will take place.

Comment: now it works thanks @noahnu